# Optimizing Travis for large logs

Tags: maven

I'm using Travis for maven project and because of large error output, I just want to look at the last 50 lines of output, so as:
`mvn -q clean verify | tail -n 50`

However, even though some of my testcases fail, the code exits with status 0 and I can't really see if the build has failed unless I run tests in local.

`Tests run: 106, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-failsafe-plugin:2.18.1:verify (default) on project easyshare-api: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /home/travis/build/au-easyshare/easyshare-api/target/failsafe-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
The command "mvn -q clean verify | tail -n 50" exited with 0.`

What would be the most optimal way to handle this? The solution *ideally* should still be valid when there're 2-3x more testcases.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed application.properties for getting shorter outputs and removed `tail -n 50`. This fixed my issue:

`spring.jpa.generate-ddl = false
spring.jpa.show-sql = false`